# how to fix htaccess error with multiple rewrite rule - ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

why this htaccess has error. it says "to many redirect" please help thanks

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://us.domain.com/ae_en/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^us\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(ae_en|ae_ar) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/ae_en/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I cannot try the wrong code, it always appear error

Comment: This line appears to be incorrect: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/ae_en/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]`...

Comment: what should be the correct line? what my goal is, i want to put 'ae_en' every url after the domain.

Comment: Well I don't understand what the purpose of that rule-set is... What are you trying to do there?

Comment: if the browser read this url:
"us.mydomain.com/anyword.html"
it will replace to "us.mydomain.com/ae_en/anyword.html"

Comment: Then change it to `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ae_en/$1 [R=301,L]`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your `.htaccess`. I would suggest both re-ordering and editing the rules.

This would be a better approach, in my opinion. I'll explain the parts below.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks

# External redirect: Remove www from domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# External redirect: Ensure language code is set
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^us\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(ae_en|ae_ar) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ae_en/$1 [R=301,L]

# Internal redirect: Pass everything non-existent to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

## Structure

First, general options and settings should come at the top and only once, i.e.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

Second, I like to get the external URL to show up correctly, so I group all external redirects here - denoted with comments in the above code block.

Third, internal "redirects" follow, meaning mapping the (now correct and final) external URL to the correct scripts.

This structure ensures that the internal scripts are only matched on a URL that will not change when re-run against the `.htaccess` on the next `RewriteRule` match.

## Omitting external redirect for `index.php`

I guess you added the `index.php` redirection handling after adding in the internal redirect, which probably has caused `index.php` to show up in the browser. So, with the above structure in place, I assume it will not show up again.

## Error in last `RewriteRule`

As Mike Rockett pointed out in the comment above, there also was an error in the last `RewriteRule`.

## Avoid redirect loop

To avoid a redirect loop when rewriting to `index.php` with the last rule, you have to explicitly exclude `index.php` from language code redirection, i.e.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php [NC]
```

Comment: Hi Jan, I still receiving this error "The us.mydomain.com page isn’t working

us.mydomain.com redirected you too many times."

Comment: Side-note: Do not let your browser cache fool you. It stores redirects, so better clear it after making these changes!