# mod_rewrite ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have an issue with mod_rewrite in apache2, I had enabled the `mod_rewrite` but doesent load I get this message: `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`

The .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteRule ^(\w+)+\/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|

RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

IDK what is wrong.

Comment: Please share the apache.conf and what is the version of Apache that you are using. Thanks.

Check these links:
http://serverfault.com/questions/595458/mod-rewrite-error-code-err-too-many-redirects

http://serverfault.com/questions/698711/getting-err-too-many-redirects-when-trying-to-access-site

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36266626/how-to-fix-htaccess-error-with-multiple-rewrite-rule-err-too-many-redirects

Comment: The error message shows that Apache fall down in an infinite loop between your redirections, so please check the previous links and check your redirect chain.

Comment: Tried but no luck, my apache.conf: http://pastebin.com/RaxWt8MG

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%/$1 [R=301]
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!=/index.php"
RewriteRule "^(.*)" "/index.php?page=$1" [L,PT]

Comment: Try that, I removed the SSL properly.

Comment: Thank you very much, now works!

Comment: I publish as answer, please mark me and approve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make the .htacess easier and clean.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%/$1 [R=301] 
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "!=/index.php" RewriteRule "^(.*)" "/index.php?page=$1" [L,PT]
```

It solution works without SSL, as main step.